# ¿Cómo soluciono el error Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException?

Tags: java, netbeans

Estoy intentando hacer un programa que lea 3 datos y al pulsar el botón "Generar" dibuje un triángulo, pero me salta el error del título, específicamente así:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
>     at listeners.Listeners.actionPerformed(Listeners.java:52)
>     at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
>     at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
>     at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
>     at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
>     at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.ja>va:252)
>     at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
>     at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
>     at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
>     at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
>     at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
>     at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
>     at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
>     at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
>     at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
>     at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
>     at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
>     at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
>     at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>     at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(P>rotectionDomain.java:76)
>     at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(P>rotectionDomain.java:86)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>     at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(P>rotectionDomain.java:76)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:20>1)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:10>5)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)

El código es:

```
package listeners;

import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Listeners extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    JButton b = new JButton("Generar");
    JTextField a1 = new JTextField();
    JTextField a2 = new JTextField();
    JTextField a3 = new JTextField();
    Graphics g = getGraphics();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Listeners m = new Listeners();
        m.setSize (400,300);
        m.setVisible(true);
    }
    Listeners(){
        super("Triangulo");
        Container c = getContentPane();
        c.setLayout(null);
        c.add(b);
        c.add(a1);
        c.add(a2);
        c.add(a3);
        b.addActionListener(this);
        b.setBounds(250,20,100,20);
        a1.setBounds(20,20,150,20);
        a2.setBounds(20,70,150,20);
        a3.setBounds(20,120,150,20);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e1) {
        double a,b,c;
        a=Integer.parseInt(a1.getText());
        b=Integer.parseInt(a2.getText());
        c=Integer.parseInt(a3.getText());
        double y=((c*c)-(b*b)+(a*a))/2*a;
        double x=a-y;
        double h=Math.sqrt((c*c)-(y*y));
        int x0p=50;
        int y0p=300;
        int x1p=(int)a+50;
        int y1p=300;
        int x2p=300+(int)x;
        int y2p=300-(int)h;
        g.drawLine(x1p, y1p, x2p, y2p);
        g.drawLine(x0p, y0p, x1p, y1p);
        g.drawLine(x0p, y0p, x2p, y2p);
    }
}
```

Ojalá puedan ayudarme

Comment: Verifica esta operación `double h=Math.sqrt((c*c)-(y*y));` puede que la operación `(c*c)-(y*y)` este dando un número negativo, lo cual **no** esta definido para la función de raiz cuadrada `Math.sqrt()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para solucionar la excepción, debes colocar el código `g.drawLine(...`) dentro de el método `paint()`

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {
   super.paint(g);
   g.drawLine(x1p, y1p, x2p, y2p);
   g.drawLine(x0p, y0p, x1p, y1p);
   g.drawLine(x0p, y0p, x2p, y2p);
}
```

Ahora, esto soluciona el problema de la Excepcion.

Answer (score 0):

Al ser un NullPointerException, la excepción se debe a que el objeto del que quieres obtener algo esta nulo o no está isntanciado. En tu caso está en el método actionPerformed. Te recomiendo, ya que las variables pueden ser a1, a2 o a3, uses un if validando que no estén nulas antes de continuar.

```
...
if (a1 != null && a2 != null && a3 != null){
    //  Puedes continuar.
}else{
    //  Uno de los objetos esta nullo.
}
...
```

Comment: Lo hice, pero aun me da el mismo error, ¿algún otro objeto podría estar en null?

Comment: Si entró, y ejecuto tu código, significa que esas 3 variables están cargadas. Algo que puede ser en todo caso son las variables b (JButton) y g (Graphic), pero de la clase. Has lo mismo, eh intenta algo mas, a la variable "b" dentro del método usa "this" para identificarla, y que no se mezcle con el boolean que definiste dentro